# Does disabling push notifications for an app revoke its APNs token?

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Does the feedback service provide indication of whether a user disabled push notification for an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, infact once the token is granted, it will not be revoked even if you reinstall the app (but will change if you restore yours/someone else's iOS installation backup or if you reinstall iOS itelf)

Also... No, you will not know which user (or device token) has stopped accepting push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Device Token is unique for the app, it only gets changed when the OS get reset.